# Error using EL in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I used El , but it is not valid .
I get an error : `javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert  1 of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long` . 1 is count.

```
     <h3>My Shopping</h3>
            <c:set var="count" value=" ${sessionScope.cart.count}" />
            ${count}
             <%--
            <c:set var="cart" value="${sessionScope.cart}" />
            <c:set var="count" value=" ${sessionScope.cart.count}" />
            <br/>
            <c:if test="${count < 1}"  >    
                No Product in your cart
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${count > 0}">
                <c:set var="listCart" value="${sessionScope.cart.cart}" />
```

Comment: Can you close the comment of remove dead code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception suggests that the `${count}` is a `String`, not a `Long` (or `Integer`, that would also work).

Provided that the `count` property of the `cart` bean in the session scope is already of the right type, then the only cause which I can see in the code posted so far is that there's a dangling leading space before the value.

```html
<c:set var="count" value=" ${sessionScope.cart.count}" />
<!-- ---------------------^                           -->
```

This effectively makes it a `String` value of `" 1"` which is obviously not a valid number. Removing that offending space should fix the problem.

Comment: thanks you. i get error from this code : `<c:if test="${count < 1}"  > `  . i fixed that :  `<c:if test="${count lt 1}"  > `   . end it running exactly

Comment: That's a different problem and happens only if you're using JSPX or Facelets instead of JSP. The `<` is a reserved character in XML.